# Read file lines into list

Tags: fish

How come `$VARS` doesn't contain `('testing', 'second')` in the following example:

```
~ ❯❯❯ /bin/cat t
testing
second
~ ❯❯❯ /bin/cat t | read -L -a VARS
~ ❯❯❯ echo $VARS
testing
~ ❯❯❯
```

I thought that `-L` is supposed to split on lines and then `-a` stores into a list. fish seems to stop after the first line, however.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why this works based on the documentation, but this is the solution:

```
~ ❯❯❯ /bin/cat t
testing
second
~ ❯❯❯ /bin/cat t | read -za VARS
~ ❯❯❯ echo $VARS
testing second
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1147).

Comment: The reason this works seems pretty clear from `man read`? `-a or --list: Stores the result as a list in a single variable.`